# Error while sending mail on https in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Below is my configuration on mail in .env file.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.domain.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`
```

When I used the `http` the above settings works fine, meaning, I can send mail to the client. But, when I used the `https` secured, it contains an error: `Connection could not be established with host mail.domain.com [Connection refused #111]`

I tried to use the port provided by the the host but still there is an error : `connection timeout`

I want to use the https since it is secured. Does anybody know how to fix this error on `https`?

Answer (score 0):

I got it worked. I just changed the Mail driver to mail:

```
`MAIL_DRIVER=mail`
```

and the Mail_port assigned by the hosting.